# Will there be a conflict

Tags: laravel, codeigniter

Will there be any conflict if you install both laravel and codeigniter in one laptop? i haven't tried it but just to be sure, i just want to know if will there be a conflict if you install both in one unit

Comment: You should be more descriptive in your title pointing out in more detail what your issue is. For instance: `Will there be a conflict if laravel and codeigniter are installed on the same computer?`

Comment: Im sorry sir, So will there be any conflict sir if i install both laravel and codeigniter in one computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not if you put them in different folders...

They are frameworks, not software applications...

You don't 'install' them you unpack and set them up